# How to access the textview on which the selection of a spinner is displayed

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to change the text of spinner selection every time a spinner item is selected based on some calculations. But i can't access the spinner selection textview .

or example i have a spinner which has 3 int values 1,2,3. if value 1 is selected i want to show the selected item as 6(1+5) instead of 1 which is the actual selected item

Comment: If I understand correct you want get selected item of the spinner ?

Comment: No. The view which shows the selected item of the spinner. I want to access that view and change text of it dynamically.

Comment: for example i have a spinner which has 3 int values 1,2,3. if value 1 is selected i want to show the selected item as 6(1+5) instead of 1 which is the actual selected item

Comment: I think you should get selected item's value, make your calculation with it, after that need to reload the spinner with the new value and set that value as selected.

Comment: show it on same spinner? or on different TextView ?

Comment: save the needed value to show in .setTag(""); and get  those value to show in textview@sreejithcr

Comment: On top of the same spinner where selected item is displayed. Not much calculations involved though  before displaying . if 1 is selected then the selected item should dsplay 1/5 and for 2, 2/5 etc..5 will be a constant. I cant figure out how to access the view on which the selection is displayed. if i can access that view i can do textview.append("/5") which will display the 'currentselected item/5' .